# Windows Phone 8, location services and Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8, geolocation, windows-phone, location

I developed an API which aims to get the location of the user and stuff like that.

I would like to test my code, so I created a **Windows Phone 8 Unit Test project**.
However, it seems that the tests which I can do are very limited, because:

- I can't switch off/on network, GPS...  => to test cases like the user
  doesn't have a location service enables on his phone;
- I can't emulate a location. The only default location I get is the default
  one of the emulator (near Seattle)

Is there a way to make some more accurate tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing consists of testing your code in complete isolation. When you have code that interacts with external resources (e.g., Location Services), you need to design [seams into your architecture](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2) which will allow you to mock out that external code.

You mentioned testing code that could behave differently when GPS is enabled/disabled. This is a good example of where a seam could be introduced. For example, consider that you had the following code:

```
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
watcher.Start();
if (watcher.Permission.Equals(GeoPositionPermission.Granted))
{
    // Do stuff that requires GPS
}
else
{
    // Handle situation where GPS is disabled
}
```

You aren't able to test this code in isolation because it is tightly coupled to the Location Services (specifically, the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` class). To address this, you can introduce an abstraction with the following interface:

```
public interface IGpsChecker
{
    bool IsGpsEnabled();
}
```

Using this interface, your code could be changed to:

```
if (m_gps_checker.IsGpsEnabled()) // m_gps_checker is supplied to your class via constructor, etc.
{
    // Do stuff that requires GPS
}
else
{
    // Handle situation where GPS is disabled
}
```

In your production code, you would provide the class with an implementation that simply uses the original logic:

```
public class LocationServicesGpsChecker : IGpsChecker
{
    public bool IsGpsEnabled()
    {
        var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        watcher.Start();

        return watcher.Permission.Equals(GeoPositionPermission.Granted);
    }
}
```

However, in your test code you would provide a [test double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Double) to the class that you're testing, giving you precise control of the conditions under which you're working.

Comment: I quite understand. Do you mean that, for example, I have to create moke test classes and fake that my GPS is ON/OFF ? For example, instead of doing  if (geolocator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled) { // throw exception...} I should replace the condition by a a moke condition: if ( m_gps_checker.IsPositionStatus()) ?

Comment: Hmmm, getting it, but with that method, how can you be sure that your code is really covered by your tests, because you fake it ? Moreover, I guess you can't moke everything. For example, if the app has no location capability, the application would crash when trying to access the location method => can't fake it, right ?

Comment: You can literally fake [any scenario you can imagine](http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2011/05/15/effective-tests-test-doubles/ "Effective Tests: Test Doubles"). For example: consider that if the app has no location capability, then the production version of `m_gps_checker.IsPositionStatusDisabled()` throws an exception (which crashes the program, if left unhandled). In your test, you could supply a fake `m_gps_checker` that throws an exception when that method is invoked, to ensure that the calling class handles the exception gracefully (i.e., without crashing). Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, but I think I'm gonna read some articles about moke tests ! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator error youre experiencing is a well known one.

Here is the work around.

> ```
> Launch your app
>
> Press the start button
>
> Open the emualtors Maps app
>
> Set your location with the emulators GPS location tool
>
> find your location with the Maps app
>
> Return to your app
> ```

Now you can use the built in visual studio network emulation tool

In most cases if you continue to update your location on the emulators GPS simulation tool it will continue to work. On occasion you will have to repeat steps 2 -> n

Comment: Yup, I know about the emulator GPS location tool. However, I would like to do that programmatically, not with any user interaction (classic Unit Tests)

Comment: @hico this process will work if you are hard coding your testing also.

Answer (score 0):

As with any other unit tests, you may have to "mock" these scenarios:

1. You may have to "mock" the scenario of location services not available.
2. You may have to prepare a hard coded set of coordinates (longitude/latitude) values to run your test with.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is what I thought about moking the scenario, however I don't know how to do this. I was hoping that the framework .NET could moke some stuff, like in Android where you can mock the GPS status and so on.